# Use of --input-fields-delimited-by in sqoop?

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, sqoop

Data in mySql table has 2 columns name and address with address field containing comma (,). Sample data as below:

Name Address

ABC   A-1102, A block, City, State

CDE   K-2309, C block, City, State

I need to import this data in hive in table with row format fields delimited by ','
How can I achieve this without doing any changes in hive table definition?

Comment: you can use --escaped-by ','   or you can replace delimiter within value while quering from sqoop like " select  REGEXP_REPLACE(col1,',','|') AS col1, col2 from tablename                                                                                   "

Comment: I tried --escaped-by but in Hive table in Address column, I am getting the data prior to the first "," only any idea why it might be so?

Comment: also tried REGEXP_REPLACE but got this error Error executing statement: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: FUNCTION retail_db.REGEXP_REPLACE does not exist
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: FUNCTION retail_db.REGEXP_REPLACE does not exist